# How to append comments array data to inside of a posts array according to postid in php?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I have posts result array and comments results array as follows

```
$postarray = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM posts");
$postids = implode('',$postarray['post_id']);
$comments = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id IN ({$postids})");
```

**`$postarray` look like like this:**

```
Array(
     [0] => Array
       (
          [post_id] => 10
          [user_id] => 24
          [content] => blah
       ) 
     [1] => Array
       (
          [post_id] => 11
          [user_id] => 2
          [content] => blah....
       ) 
)
```

**`$comments` is like this:**

```
Array(
     [0] => Array
       (
          [com_id] => 1
          [post_id] => 10
          [user_id] => 2
          [content] => blah
       ) 
     [1] => Array
       (
          [com_id] => 4
          [post_id] => 11
          [user_id] => 7
          [content] => blah....
       ) 
       ........................
)
```

I am looking for add `$comments` data into `$postarray` like this:

```
Array(
     [0] => Array
       (
          [post_id] => 10
          [user_id] => 24
          [content] => blah
          [comments] =>  Array(
                            [0] => Array
                                 (
                                     [com_id] => 1
                                     [post_id] => 10
                                     [user_id] => 2
                                     [content] => blah
                                  ) 
                            [1] => Array
                                  (
                                    [com_id] => 8
                                    [post_id] => 10
                                    [user_id] => 7
                                    [content] => blah....
                                  ) 
        )
       ) 
     [1] => Array
       (
          [post_id] => 11
          [user_id] => 2
          [content] => blah....
          [comments] =>
       ) 
)
```

How do I append `$postarray` with `$comments` like this?

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard if you read a bit about loops, associative arrays etc. To help a bit: loop through each $postarray element and add a new property "comments" to it (blank array). Then, make use of indexes in this loop to get your comments inside ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce`:

```
$posts = array_reduce($posts, function ($result, $post) use ($comments) {
    $post['comments'] = array();

    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        if ($comment['post_id'] != $post['post_id']) {
            continue;
        }
        $post['comments'][] = $comment;
    }

    $result[] = $post;

    return $result;
}, array());
```

Comment: I think the OP will have a hard time understanding your code since this should be a fairly easy task :) Good work though.

Comment: It's good to be hard.. Maybe he will learn something new.. and if it's hard.. for sure he will remember it later :)

Comment: if OP wants to learn more than its good (always good), else, follow the basic methods..

Comment: I think sometimes it's better to take a simpler approach, especially when learning :)

Comment: @Matei Mihai Thank you for the ans. Iam trying to avoid fetching comments for each postid an d avoid sql query loops.. I will check this answer...

Comment: Guys.. I don't see where is the hard part in my answer.. really.. It's very clear how it works.. `array_reduce` is very well documented and the function body contains only basic code..

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that:

```
$post = array(
    array(
        'post_id'=>10,
        'user_id'=>24,
        'content'=>'blah'
        ),
    array(
        'post_id'=>11,
        'user_id'=>2,
        'content'=>'blah'
        )
    );

$comments = array(
    array(
        'com_id'=>1,
        'post_id'=>10,
        'user_id'=>24,
        'content'=>'blah'
        ),
    array(
        'com_id'=>1,
        'post_id'=>11,
        'user_id'=>24,
        'content'=>'blah'
        )
    );

$expectedArr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
    $expectedArr[$i]['post_id'] = $value['post_id'];
    $expectedArr[$i]['user_id'] = $value['user_id'];
    $expectedArr[$i]['content'] = $comments[$i]['content'];
    $expectedArr[$i]['comments'] = $comments;
    $i++;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($expectedArr);
```

**Result Is:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 10
            [user_id] => 24
            [content] => blah
            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [com_id] => 1
                            [post_id] => 10
                            [user_id] => 24
                            [content] => blah
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [com_id] => 1
                            [post_id] => 11
                            [user_id] => 24
                            [content] => blah
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 11
            [user_id] => 2
            [content] => blah
            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [com_id] => 1
                            [post_id] => 10
                            [user_id] => 24
                            [content] => blah
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [com_id] => 1
                            [post_id] => 11
                            [user_id] => 24
                            [content] => blah
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use like this function :

```
function array_extend($a, $b) {
        foreach($b as $k=>$v) {
            if( is_array($v) ) {
                if( !isset($a[$k]) OR isset($v[0])) {
                    $a[] = $v;
                } else {
                    $a[] = array_extend($a[$k], $v);
                }
            } else {
                $a[] = $v;
            }
        }
        return $a;
    }
```

Uses:

```
$array = array_extend($orig_array,$new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same experience this week with formatting my data as you want to do there.

here is the following solution I got :

```
<?php

foreach ($postarray as $postArrayRow) {

  foreach ($comments as $commentRow) {

    if ($postarrayRow['id'] == $commentRow['post_id']) {

      if(array_key_exists($postarrayRow['comments'], $postArrayRow)){
        postarrayRow['comments'] = array(commentRow);
      }

      $postarrayRow['comments'][] = $commentRow ;

    }
  }
}
```

Tell me if it's good for you. And try `print_r($postarray) ;` to see if it's formatted as you want !

Answer (score 0):

Do it like first get all posts and then in a for loop get comments for each post.

```
    $output = array();
    $postarray = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM posts");
    foreach($postarray as $post)
    {
        $post['comments'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ({$post->id})");
        $output[] = $post;
    }
    return $output;
```